# Joomla Update System For Paid Extensions

Tags: one-click-updates, extension-update

I'm trying to make this Joomla Update system work for paid extensions.

How I'm going about it is as follows:

- I'm using [Mohameds](https://github.com/mabdelaziz77/downloadid-custom-field) downloadid.php to populate "extra_query" field in the "_update_sites" table.

  - after you check for updates joomla looks into your xml file and checks for new versions
  - then after it sees a new update is available and you click on update
  - it follows the link in the xml updateserver file adding "?dlid=35423542354" at the end of it
- I have download.php file at my end that does the following: GET the variable "dlid" from the url, check it against my database/subscription system and return the file or not

[Check the project here](https://github.com/kyuzo1/Joomla-Update-System-For-Paid-Extensions)

Comment: Things have started working, I haven't changed anything in the code.
I do suspect that clearing the cache did the trick (doh!)
I've developed the update server handler which logs all access attempts and queries the database for a valid subscription if one is found serves you the update file. I can share the file and the process in the tutorial if anyone is interested. Anyone?

Comment: Please share, it can help other researchers.

Comment: I have developed this solution to use with Akeeba Subs and Akeeba Release System, but I think you are using it with a custom solution, right? please give some information about your development environment.

Comment: @mohamed-abdelaziz Yes, I'm using a custom solution, a combination of 2 free components, phocaDownload and [link](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/pay-per-download/) PayPerDownload - for a free component it has everything you need when setting up in tandem they work quite flawlessly. 
I have it all ready for production but one thing is stopping me, and that is the file download to users website. All preliminary checks work and I can download the file manually but when sending the file to joomla update process fails with "Warning-Update path does not exist." , headers maybe?

Comment: @zollie I'm having trouble sending the file in the correct manner to Joomla, I've tried a lot of combinations. using php header redirect - it does not work if I point it to a local file "download/mod_module.zip" or if I use [zip header](https://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/) techniques, It does work however if I point php header redirect to some public phocaDownload link which leads me to believe that the only problem left is sending the file back to the user in the required way

Comment: @Mohamed check it out

Comment: @Kyuzo - thanks for sharing it, I'll check this out later.

Comment: @Kyuzo thanks for sharing, I will have a look.